# how to send UDP data/packet using Socket programming without converting it into bytes using python?

Tags: python, sockets

I tried to create a UDP socket and was successful in creating one.
Now when I tried to send some raw data, `socket.send` wants me to convert it into bytes.
But this raw data is a command to change the time of my application which I am working on, so i wanted to send the data as it is.
Is there a way to send this without converting it into bytes?

here's the code i used:

```
Socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
bufferSize = 1024
recvBuf = 4096           
new_pkt= x00\x1c\x7fb\xb5\xfd\x00PV\xb8\x08\x9f\x08\x00E\x00\x000B\xad\x00\x00\x80\x11\x00\x00\n\xe7\xa0\xc6\n\xe7\x922\xc0\xb8\x05\xdc\x00\x1cH\xf4\t\x8d\x01\x00\x01\x01\x00\x10\x00\x00\x01,\x00\x00\x00\x004\xe6\xc0
S = Socket.connect_ex(("10.231.146.50",port))    
Socket.settimeout(10)   

Res = Socket.sendall(new_pkt)

Socket.close
```

obtained an error to convert the packet into bytes, while trying to send it

Comment: you might want to include the programming language as a tag.

Comment: Ya i have added it. I am using python 2.7

Comment: Please edit the question to fix the syntax errors in your code.

Comment: And to include the 'error to convert the packet into bytes', whatever that might be. To answer the question in your title, you can't.

Comment: I get this error with Python3, but not with Python2.7: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: So that says you need the opposite of what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I get no error with *Python2.7*, for send or sendall, if I put double quotes around your data string

```
new_pkt= "x00\x1c\x7fb\xb5\xfd\x00PV\xb8\x08\x9f\x08\x00E\x00\x000B\xad\x00\x00\x80\x11\x00\x00\n\xe7\xa0\xc6\n\xe7\x922\xc0\xb8\x05\xdc\x00\x1cH\xf4\t\x8d\x01\x00\x01\x01\x00\x10\x00\x00\x01,\x00\x00\x00\x004\xe6\xc0"
```

Give it a try ;-)

If you use *Python3.x*, you need bytes. So you just prefix your string with a `b`:

```
new_pkt_for_py3 = b"x00\x1c\x7fb\xb5\xfd...."
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the help. I tried it, the packet is going but when i checked it in wireshark it is showing unknown packet. For whatever reason I am sending the functionality is also not happening? What could be the reason?

Comment: What kind of packet should this be? What do you expect? What raw data did wireshark show? Try this: [https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication]